# Conditional routing on Symfony

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4

We have a Symfony app already deployed, in which we decide to use URL like `organization.app-name-domain.com` to show information about organizations listed on our DB. To make this we write our routing.yml like this:

```
homepage:
     url:   /
     class: sfDomainRoute
     param: { module: home, action: index }
     requirements:
          sf_host: [<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_urlapp') ?>, www.<?php echo sfConfig::get('app_urlapp')."]\n" ?>

homepage_org:
     url:   /
     class: sfDomainRoute
     param: { module: org, action: show }
```

Now we are deploying exact the same app in another domain, that is a subdomain of a third partner. The new app URL is like `app-name.partner-domain.com`.

And therefore we cannot let the organizations as subdomains, not on the same way as we used to.

Is not a big problem we can change the `routing.yml` of the new app to a more commonly URLs like `app-name.partner-domain.com/organization` but this is not smooth enough for me, cause we want to keep both apps depending from the same repository etc...

The possible solution that comes to my head was make the routing manually on `frontendConfiguration.class.php` depending of the name of the app defined on `app.yml`. But I cannot access the routing app instance. `sfContext::getRoutes()` returns `null`.

I got the idea of make conditional routing from Symfony 1.0 [HERE](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System#chapter_09_sub_creating_rules_without_routing_yml).

Any idea of how we can reproduce that code on Symfony 1.4?